# Serverless proxy of custom domain (with sub domain) to S3 endpoint

Tags: amazon-s3, proxy, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, serverless-framework

### What I have

I have an S3 bucket named `example-dev.com` configured for web hosting.

My S3 bucket has several child folders named `client-site.com` or `big-project.com`. So on S3 the URL to access the dev homepage for `client-site.com` is `example-dev.com.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/client-site.com/index.html`. This carries over to about a dozen sites, and the list of sites changes regularly as clients come and go.

### What I'm trying to do

I'm trying to map that raw S3 URL to a sub domain of my `example-dev.com` custom domain. I want:

`client-site.com` `.example-dev.com` `/index.html`

to serve the file at

`example-dev.com.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/` `client-site.com` `/index.html`

I would use DNS for the mappings, but there is a child folder for each site and the folders change regularly.

**I'd like to do this using serverless architecture if possible.** I have a version of this that works just fine using [`http-proxy`](https://github.com/nodejitsu/node-http-proxy) on a node server, but I wanna see if it's possible without a VPS. I think I'm meant to use API Gateway and/or Lambda, but I'm struggling to wrap my head around API Gateway and I don't know if Lambda is capable of remapping requests the same way http-proxy does.

Any help is appreciated, thanks very much!

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't really sound like you need API Gateway for this problem unless I'm missing something.

Sounds like you need to go into your DNS and create an CNAME entry called `client-site.com.example-dev.com` and point that at the S3 bucket directly. In that case you would have to create an S3 bucket for each 'child folder'. I don't know if that is something you can change.

But this could all be done with DNS rather than paying for any type of proxy just to map the request path.

Comment: Thanks, that's a really valid solution in most cases and it's what I do on my personal site. In my case the client sites I'm working on change frequently, so I'm having the server remap them dynamically instead of constantly creating and deleting DNS records. I've updated my question to clarify this.

Answer (score 1):

This should be possible with S3 behind CloudFront and Lambda@Edge, once it is out of preview (or if you can get in on the preview, but there's a wait for that if they are still accepting preview requests), because you can read the HTTP headers and modify the request URI in flight -- prepending part of the host header to the path.

For the moment, though, @JackKohn-AWS's solution can be implemented with one level of simplification: you don't have to edit DNS for each site.

You can create a wildcard CNAME in Route 53 for *.example.com pointing directly to s3-website-[region].amazonaws.com.  Then, all you need to do is create buckets in that region, named for the test site you want to create, e.g. client.example.org.example.com -- because after you create the Route 53 wildcard, DNS is already set up for any valid bucket name ending in .example.com in that region.

This works because of an impliementation detail in S3 --
the actual CNAME target you use does not actually have to be the web site endpoint for the bucket that is shown in the console -- it only needs to be the base name for the regional website hosting endpoint.  The resolution path has no role in which bucket serves the request.  As long as it arrives at the right regional endpoint, the Host header identifies the bucket.

This isn't what you asked for, since it's one bucket per client site, but once the DNS is configured with the wildcard CNAME, any bucket you create with a matching name is already wired up to resolve.

---

This should not be impossible in API Gateway, but it seems outside the intended usage there.  Response bodies have a 10 MB payload limit.

Comment: This is a pretty clever solution, thanks for sharing. I'll definitely keep my eye on Lambda@Edge

Comment: Okay, so I was curious and had to try to see if I could get API Gateway to do this.  Preliminary results are promising: `curl -v https://ca5example.execute-api.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/test/pics/funny/cat.png` returns the *expected* error from my bucket that indicates that I've successfully remapped the standard hostname as a path prefix (less the API "stage" name `/test`, which you can omit with custom domains): `Code: NoSuchKey` `Message: The specified key does not exist.` `Key: ca5example.execute-api.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/pics/funny/cat.png`. So it may indeed be possible to make this work.

Comment: Curiously, the console would have me believe it is not going to work. There's an orange triangle next to the Endpoint URL that appears when I include the Host header, which I've mapped in the method request and created as a path parameter with the same name in the integration request.
`The endpoint you have entered contains parameters that are not defined in the resource path. Parameters are case sensitive.`  But... it does work, so far.

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to install nginx on a host ec2 and use proxypass to proxy the request to s3 content. That way you can carry on accessing the content with the friendly url client-site.com.example-dev.com. Your DNS record will now have to point to the host ec2 machine which will use nginx to route the request to appropriate backend s3 content depending on the url accessed.

You can also have multiple listener for different client

To install nginx

```
yum nginx install
```

Nginx config should contain:

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name client-site.com.example-dev.com;

        location / {
                proxy_pass http://example-dev.com.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/client-site.com/index.html;
                proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
                proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
        }

}
```